# How to use CoreMotion without sprite kit to tilt image to the left and to the right

Tags: objective-c

How to use CoreMotion without sprite kit to tilt image to the left and to the right

Hi all,

Im currently trying to research how to use core motion framework without sprite kit. Could not find any on the web. Can anyone demonstrate how to move an image right when iPhone is tilted right. and something when it is tilted left without the use of the sprite kit.

```
 this is what i have so far. does this look correct?

CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/10.0;

if (!motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable) {

    CGPointMake(Bird.center.x-1, Bird.center.y-upmovement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the construction of the motion manager down, but you forgot to start getting updates.

Here is a working example based off of what you provided.

```
CMMotionManager* motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/27; // 27 frames per second

// Start the motion manager with our queue
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue: [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                   withHandler: ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    CGFloat multiplier;
    CGPoint newPosition;
    if ( !motionManager || !Bird ) //make sure it is safe to invoke the motion manager, and the view.
        return;

    // The Movement Multiplier
    multiplier = 200;

    // The center point of which the view will reside
    newPosition = Bird.superview.center;

    // Calculate our new position
    newPosition.x += motion.attitude.roll * multiplier;
    newPosition.y += motion.attitude.pitch * multiplier;

    // Move the view in the main thread so it can be rendered correctly.
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        Bird.center = newPosition;
    });

}];
```

It should move the bird view on both x, and y axis.